# When should a file be closed inside a function?

Tags: c

I would like to know why you don't need to close the file inside the function since locally inside the function there's an open file. when the function ends does it close it, or i am not understanding something?

```
#include <stdio.h>
void function(FILE *file) {
    char c;
    c = getc(file);
    printf("%c",c);
    //fclose()?
}

int main() {
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("arq.txt","r");
    function(file);
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The general rule is that the part of the code that allocates a resource is usually responsible for cleaning it up. If you open a file inside a function, you usually close it there. If you open it outside the function, you usually close it outside.

Comment: There is no rule on whether you should close it inside or not. It depends on your needs. This example is too simple and lacks context. It might make sense to close the file inside the function depending on the context.

Comment: There are many exceptions, but you usually know when they're necessary.

Comment: Your code is too simplified to make any sense out of. Your code passes garbage to `function` because `file` is never assigned a value.